# callable parameters not being passed

Tags: php

in php, using a 'callable' and type hinting. When I invoke the callable with more than one arguments, the method only receives the first. no matter how many, or how I invoke it. any ideas?

various invoke methods
changing parameter types

`$this->class_instance($class_name)->method_reference($method_name)(...$method_args);`

inside callable see more than only the first parameter

Comment: All parameters must be within the brackets: `$this->method($arg1, $arg2, $arg3)`

Comment: grant C - no...

Answer (score 1):

The problem was how I was constructing the callable.

I was constructing the callable inside of a closure, which was handling argument passing. I just had to expand the arguments there (inside the closure).